# Unity 2D Bounce Back moving object when colliding with another object

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision

I have an object that, after receiving its respective input, it moves this way:

```
mov = new Vector3((Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * vel), 0, 0);
transform.position += mov;
```

But, I want it to bounce back, once it collides with an object.

I´ve made the procedures already (`OnCollisionEnter2D(Collsion2D col){bla bla...}`), but I need help with what happens on the collision (bouncing back the object)....

I´ve tried giving the collided object a **bouncing material**, but it just slows it a bit, my guess is that because of the constant force given by the acceleration.

Greetings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are teleporting the object at the current time. instead you should use the Rigidbody.addForce this will add a force in the specified direction thus if you do the opposite direction will "bounce" of the object. Another option would be to create a physics material then not bother with the code.

Comment: Well, I did't addForce (though I tried it) because I was already using translations and I just learned that it's not good to merge both in a same contexts/ I gave the collision object a sharedMaterial with bouncincess and worked just the way I wanted it.

Answer (score 1):

If you move the object with transform.position what you are doing is basically a "teleport" so it will ignore the bouncing material. If you want it to bounce you have to write the physics code to detect a collision and change the movement or you can do addforce to move the object and it will detect collisions and react automatically.

Comment: Yup, actually I just learned that it is not good idea to merge both translations and physics between 2 objects.

Comment: Consider also using addforce with impulse to simulate fun bouncing on collision

Answer (score 0):

You are not using materials, right?

See if the content of this post may help you, the OP is using a formula using Raycast and the answer guides him to use the Raycast with [Layers Maks](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Layers.html):

[2D bouncing formula doesn't work properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27988983/2d-bouncing-formula-doesnt-work-properly)

There is this one also with fixed angles (like **Pong**), but it uses material (with values: *friction*: 0, *bounciness*: 1):
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/70294/get-gameobject-to-bounce-of-colliders

But if nothing makes sense and you are going crazy and might want to start from zero, there is this official video tutorial on bouncing and sliding in 2D:
https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/2d/sliding-bouncing-2d

Comment: Thanks, I Tried giving the boxCollider2d of the object a sharedMaterial with bounciness and it worked!!